# Bridged native module not showing in React Native [macOS]

Tags: objective-c, react-native, react-native-macos

- Note that I am working with [React Native for macOS](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-macos)

I made (actually, not complete) a [module](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios) that bridges [NSOpenPanel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsopenpanel?language=objc) and [NSSavePanel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssavepanel?language=objc). Here's my `RCTPanel.m`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#import "RCTPanel.h"

@implementation RCTPanel

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(open)
{
  NSOpenPanel *panel;
  
  if ([panel runModal] == NSModalResponseOK)
  {
    // TODO
  }
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(save)
{
  NSSavePanel *panel;

  if ([panel runModal] == NSModalResponseOK)
  {
    //TODO
  }
}
```

and here's my testing code `App.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, NativeModules, View } from "react-native";

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Button title='OPEN' onPress={ () => NativeModules.Panel.open() }/>
                <Button title='SAVE' onPress={ () => NativeModules.Panel.save() }/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

When I run `npx react-native run-macos`, the app shows fine, but when I press buttons which I made, Open/Save panel does not shows up. no error message.

I first thought [asking to Microsoft](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-macos/issues)(which maintains react-native-macos),
but it doesn't seems like a bug. more to be my mistake. so I'm asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSOpenPanel *panel;
  
if ([panel runModal] == NSModalResponseOK)
{
    // TODO
}
```

Note that your first line only designates a `panel` variable, it doesn't actually create the panel itself. In manual-reference-counting, it would be a junk (uninitialized) pointer, but may be `nil` in ARC. In any case, sending the `-runModal` message to `nil` is simply ignored and nothing happens, which is the behavior you describe.

Change the lines to `NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];` and `NSSavePanel *panel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];` and they should work properly.

In Objective-C, if things don't happen like they should, it's always a good idea to check to see if some value that you think exists is not, in fact, `nil`.

Comment: Oh, Thanks! now it throws another error, but at least now I can know what is problem.